# Angularjs filter ng-repeat by datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angularjs-filter

Can someone help me to filter my ng-repeat using datepicker?,
I'm not that expert when it comes to these and I'm still in the learning process. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

**here is my html:**

```
<form style=" text-align: center;">  
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

        <div class="col-lg-6"  name="in">
            <label>Time In</label>
              <div ng-init="getTime()">
                <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: date_picker">

                {{item.last_name}}
                {{item.first_name}}
                <input type="checkbox"/> <img src="{{item.pic}}" width="100" height="100"><br>
                {{item.time_only}}
                {{item.date_only}} <br><br>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**My controller:**

```
function ($scope, $http, $filter, $timeout, $resource, ngTableParams, $modal, time) {


      $scope.items=[];


       $scope.today = function() {
          $scope.dt = new Date();
        };
        $scope.today();

        $scope.clear = function () {
          $scope.dt = null;
        };

        $scope.toggleMin = function() {
          $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
        };
        $scope.toggleMin();

        $scope.open = function($event) {
          $event.preventDefault();
          $event.stopPropagation();

          $scope.opened = true;
        };

        $scope.dateOptions = {
          formatYear: 'yy',
          startingDay: 1
        };

        $scope.formats = [ 'yyyy/MM/dd','dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
        $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];




        $scope.getTime = function(){
              time.getTime()
              .success(function(data) {console.log(data);
                    $scope.items = data.items;

                   })
                     .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                               console.log('error!');
                   });
        };
```

Comment: how precise do you want the filter to be?  24 hour range?

Comment: Yes, I want to filter all the data having the same date on my datepicker. Like for example, if my datepicker is today, I want to show only all the data having the same date as today and then if I choose another date on my datepicker, it will filter again the ng-repeat and show only those date having the same date as the I choose on my datepicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code from

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: date_picker">
```

to

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {date_only:dt}">
```

Assuming that ng-model=dt is your search criteria and property searched against is item.date_only and also both above object has same type ( comparable ).

More info check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Hi I tried this one but it seems it does not get the date on my ng-repeat.

Comment: It works now. I just forget to filter in my controller. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter that takes whatever day you have selected in the datepicker as a parameter. From there you need to set the time for the date object you get from the datepicker (because it returns whatever date with the current time) so that it creates a range from midnight to 11:59PM.

Filter:

```
app.filter('dayFilter', function() {

  return function(items, date) {
    var filtered = [];
    var begin, end

    begin = date.setHours(0,0,0);
    end = date.setHours(23,59,59);
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
        if(item > begin && item < end) {
          filtered.push(item)
        }
    })
    return filtered
  }
});
```

Then apply the filter to your ng-repeat:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="d in data | dayFilter:day">{{d}}</li>
</ul>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wkEGwzIfhv3tQ2Gg3W0d?p=preview)